# Is one allowed to chew gum on Shabbos without an Eiruv?

Tags: shabbat, food, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

If food is in my hand, I would assume I'm not allowed to carry it. What about, though, if it's in my mouth? For example: chewing gum or sucking a candy.

Would those be permissible outside where there's no eiruv? And if not, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [Mishna](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=92&format=text) in Shabbos that says: "[If someone takes out with] his mouth ... he is not liable".

Tosefos asks on that from a [Mishna](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=35&daf=13b&format=text) in Krisos which says: "One could eat one thing and be obligated four Chatases... R' Meir said 'if it was Shabbos and someone carried, he is obligated.'"

Tosphos answers that the difference is that food is customarily carried in the mouth while other objects are not (if one carries something in a not-normal way one did not violate Torah law).

So carrying food in the mouth is a biblical prohibition. Carrying anything else in the mouth is a Rabbinic prohibition. Either way it is forbidden.

Comment: Do you happen to know the reason for the Rabbinic prohibition?

Comment: @yydl Carrying with a shinui is Rabbinicly prohibited the same way any other Shabbos violation done with a shinui is prohibited.

Comment: But why is, say, carrying clothes or glasses not a shinui, and stuff in mouth, yes?

Comment: @yydl clothes and glasses aren't being carried, but worn,therefore one is permitted to be worn even by rabbinic law.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot carry in your mouth either.

Comment: And if not, why not?

Comment: @yydl: Well, "why not" would seem obvious: because it, too, is called "_hotzaa_". But a source (or argument) is necessary for that assertion!

Comment: @yydl, the mishna in eiruvin says that even if you are walking around with a spittle in your mouth, you would be chayav.

Comment: Shabbat 92a says yuo can carry in your mouth because it's not the customary way to carry.  So, as noted in Shmuel's answer, maybe food is different, but your blanket statment contradicts that source so a further source would be helpful.